# How to define unique index on multiple columns in sequelize

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

How do I define a unique index on a combination of columns in sequelize. For example I want to add a unique index on user_id, count and name.

```
var Tag = sequelize.define('Tag', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        user_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false,
        },
        count: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: true
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true,
        })
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can refer to this doc http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#indexes

You will need to change your definition like shown below and call sync

```
var Tag = sequelize.define('Tag', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        allowNull: false,
    },
    count: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        allowNull: true
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
    }
},
{
    indexes: [
        {
            unique: true,
            fields: ['user_id', 'count', 'name']
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Neither do any of the answers below. I'm trying to run a query equivalent to this: `CREATE TABLE scores (id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, oppId INT NOT NULL, oppType TEXT NOT NULL, tree TEXT NOT NULL, version INT NOT NULL, score JSON NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT uniq_scores UNIQUE(oppId, oppType, tree, version));`. When I use the unique indexes with sequelize I'm still able to create two rows with the same values in those columns. Anyone else have these issues?

Comment: @clu it because only process in sequelize itself

Answer (score 68):

> I have same issue to applied composite unique constraint to multiple
>   columns but nothing work with Mysql, Sequelize(4.10.2) and NodeJs
>   8.9.4 finally I fixed through following code.

```
queryInterface.createTable('actions', {
  id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
  },
  system_id: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      unique: 'actions_unique',
  },
  rule_id: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      unique: 'actions_unique',
  },
  plan_id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      unique: 'actions_unique',
  }
}, {
  uniqueKeys: {
      actions_unique: {
          fields: ['system_id', 'rule_id', 'plan_id']
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Calling sync is bad for keeping a migration trail.

Comment: Also, for me just mentioning `unique: 'actions_unique'` for the columns I wanted to be in composite unique rule worked. Didn't add the `uniqueKeys` option.

Comment: Can confirm that with MySQL 5.7 and Sequelize 5.21.2 just mentioning unique tags on the corresponding fields don't do a thing; only `uniqueKeys` seem to work. Checked by running migrations with and without the thing, then checking mySQL with 'show create table'.

Comment: Geez. Works for postgres as well.

Answer (score 16):

If the accepted one is not working then try the below code. It worked for me in my case rather the accepted one.

```
var Tag = sequelize.define('Tag', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        allowNull: false,
        unique: 'uniqueTag',
    },
    count: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        allowNull: true,
        unique: 'uniqueTag',
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        unique: 'uniqueTag',
    }
});
```

Comment: Must not be used now. Will not work with `alter: true` option in sync...

Comment: Hi @RahmatAli didn't understand  where I used `alter: true`

Comment: You can use `alter: true` in the `sync` function of the `sequelize`. So, when the `sequelize` syncs the `models` with database, `sequelize` alters the database columns with the changed columns from models.

It is recommended to use the `unique` attribute through `indexes`. Else, there will be some error if you use it with `alter: true` in `sync` function. Please refer to the document for more about `alter` attribute: [link](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html)

Answer (score 6):

I tried to create an index on a single column.
This worked for me. Hope this helps.

Model

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Tag = sequelize.define(
    "Tag",
    {
      name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true },
      nVideos: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    {
      indexes: [
        {
          unique: true,
          fields: ["name"]
        }
      ]
    }
  );

  return Tag;
};
```

Migration

```js
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable(
      "Tags",
      {
        id: {
          allowNull: false,
          autoIncrement: true,
          primaryKey: true,
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
        name: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
          unique: "unique_tag"
        },
        nVideos: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER },
        createdAt: {
          allowNull: false,
          type: Sequelize.DATE
        },
        updatedAt: {
          allowNull: false,
          type: Sequelize.DATE
        }
      },
      {
        uniqueKeys: {
          unique_tag: {
            customIndex: true,
            fields: ["name"]
          }
        }
      }
    );
  },
  down: queryInterface => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable("Tags");
  }
};
```

Comment: @Sandeep you are a savior. tried so many options, only this worked for me. Big Thank you.

Comment: Could not get this to work with these versions..
"sequelize": "^6.3.5", "sequelize-hierarchy": "git+https://github.com/jsanta/sequelize-hierarchy.git"

Answer (score 3):

I prefer sequelize sync method with composite unique, If not passing indexes name u will get a error as below on adding many indexes in index array.

> error: SequelizeDatabaseError: Identifier name 'LONG_NAME' is too long

```
module.exports = function (sequelize: any, DataTypes: any) {
return sequelize.define('muln_user_goals_transaction', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(),
        allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(),
        allowNull: false,
    },
    phone: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(),
        allowNull: false,
    },
    amount: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(8),
        allowNull: false
    },
    deleted: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false,
    },
}, {
    tableName: 'muln_user_goals_transaction',
    timestamps: false,
    indexes: [
        {
            name: 'unique_index',
            unique: true,
            fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'amount', 'deleted']
        }
    ],
    defaultScope: {
        where: {
            deleted: false
        }
    }
});
};
```

Comment: All I needed was to know that you can add `'deleted'` to the index, in case you are handling soft delete. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sequelize composite unique (manual)

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Model', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      fieldOne: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        unique: 'uniqueTag',
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: 'Model1',
          key: 'id'
        },
        onUpdate: 'cascade',
        onDelete: 'cascade'
      },
      fieldsTwo: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        unique: 'uniqueTag',
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: 'Model2',
          key: 'id'
        },
        onUpdate: 'cascade',
        onDelete: 'cascade'
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    })
    .then(function() {
      return queryInterface.sequelize.query(
        'ALTER TABLE `UserFriends` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`fieldOne`, `fieldTwo`)'
      );
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Model');
  }
};
```

Comment: got error `SequelizeDatabaseError: syntax error at or near "\`"`
fixed by using `'ALTER TABLE "UserFriends" ADD UNIQUE ("fieldOne", "fieldTwo")'`