# Using Unqiue keys in mysql - Sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, composite-key, unique-key

My table model called 'Contact' :

```
var Contact = sequelize.define('contact', {
  userKey: Sequelize.STRING,
  gsm: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      unique: true,
      required: true
  },
  firstName: Sequelize.STRING,
  lastName: Sequelize.STRING,
)}
```

For example, if a user login and post the data via form as inputs: userKey, gsm , firstname, lastname like this
1234, mohamed, sameer , KKKK (userKey coming from his loginSession)

I stored this datas in mysql with the userKey
So if the user again add same gsm ,

it will alert as **gsm must be unique**

But My problem is if user with different userKey enters into application and post the datas, he wants to add the same gsm which was added by another user.

PS:  There is only one table called **Contact**

Is it possible to do with composite keys or sequelize Hooks?

My api.js:

```
exports.addNewContact = function (req, res) {
    var newcontact = {
        userKey: req.user.userKey, (// coming from login user session key)
        gsm: req.body.gsm,
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
    }
     Contact.create(newcontact).then(function (data){
        return res.status(200).send(data);
    }).catch(Sequelize.ValidationError, function (err) {
        return res.status(422).send(err.errors[0].message);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        return res.status(400).send(err.message);
    });
```

Comment: Please check [here](http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/2.0/docs/models-definition/) example

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got answer:

I changed my models looks like this:

```
var Contact = sequelize.define('contact', {
    userKey: Sequelize.STRING,
    role: Sequelize.STRING,
    gsm: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        required: true
    },
    firstName: Sequelize.STRING,
    lastName: Sequelize.STRING
}, {
    indexes: [{
        unique: true,
        fields: ['userKey', 'gsm']
    }]
})
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42199137/7862193