# How to define an index, within a Sequelize model?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a simple non-unique index for one of my SQL columns, inside a Sequelize model. I tried to follow this post :[How to define unique index on multiple columns in sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42195348/how-to-define-unique-index-on-multiple-columns-in-sequelize) .

This is my code:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Item = sequelize.define('Item', {
        itemId:  DataTypes.STRING,
        ownerId:  DataTypes.INTEGER,
        status: DataTypes.STRING,
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        nature: DataTypes.STRING,
        content: DataTypes.STRING,
        moment: DataTypes.BIGINT,
        indexes:[
            {
                unique: 'false',
                fields:['ownerId']
            }
        ]

    });

    return Item;
};
```

I get this error:

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near '[object Object], `createdAt`
>   DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, P' at line 1

The code that i have in my server.js file is this:

```
models.sequelize.sync().then(function () {
    server.listen(port, () => {
        console.log('server ready')
    })
});
```

What is wrong with my setup? Is there any other way this can be done with Sequelize?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Almost there. You should add indexes in a new object like this:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Item = sequelize.define('Item', {
        itemId:  DataTypes.STRING,
        ownerId:  DataTypes.INTEGER,
        status: DataTypes.STRING,
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        nature: DataTypes.STRING,
        content: DataTypes.STRING,
        moment: DataTypes.BIGINT
    },
    {
      indexes:[
       {
         unique: false,
         fields:['ownerId']
       }
      ]
    });

    return Item;
};
```

Comment: Hehe. If this solves this issue, then please accept my answer :)

Comment: I will, in 4 minutes, when it allows me to :D

Comment: @Roi Does it need to be the actual field which is in table or the field name which is mentioned in define of the code

Comment: @Root I'm not sure what you mean by that. The field name which is inserted into the fields array corresponds to one of the fields in the Item model. Correct me if I am wrong, but these names will also always reflect the names of the fields in the database table.

Comment: @Roi suppose there is one model definition having column as 
ItemId: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      field: 'item_id',
      autoIncrement: true
    }

In this what should the index be?
ItemId or item_id

Comment: upvoted! if ownerId was a date instead how would you make it DESC

Comment: how to define on 'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('tables', {
      id: {

Answer (score 6):

It can work in single migration also.

In my case, just perform the addIndex after createTable method in the migration file

**Migration:**

```
return queryInterface.createTable('Item', {
    // columns...
}).then(() => queryInterface.addIndex('Item', ['OwnerId']))
.then(() => {
    // perform further operations if needed
});
```

it's work for me in the migration file.

Comment: Yeah, but why go in two steps, when you can do it in just one?